# Python and Selenium xpath text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

How can I get the text of the following xpath:

```
.//*[@id='answer']/section/table/tbody/tr[45]/td[4]/text()[1]
```

Here is the HTML segment I'm trying to get:

```
...
<td>first part<span id="divider">/</span>second part of column</td>
...
```

I have something like:

```
url = ".//*[@id='answer']/section/table/tbody/tr[45]/td[4]/text()[1]"
value = browser.find_element_by_xpath(url)
```

then I tried:

```
print value.text
print value.get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

But I have an error with both

UPDATE:
Here are the errors I have 
With **text**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "select_element.py", line 195, in <module>
print value.text
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 73, in text
return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 493, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element.
```

With **get_attribute**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "select_element.py", line 195, in <module>
    print value.get_attribute("innerHTML")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 139, in get_attribute
self, name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 491, in execute_script
'args': converted_args})['value']
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: a.getAttributeNode is not a function
```

Thanks,
Arty

Comment: And what is the error...

Comment: I updated the question with the Traceback and error I have

Comment: @Arty: Did you get back the element? i.e. did you check the output of `value` alone?

Comment: the xpath part /text()[1] look suspicious. Is it an <input> element? If so, you should be getting back another error as other commenters are implying, before you ever can ask for the element's text attribute. If you're getting an error during the browser.find_element_by_xpath(url), it could be because the xpath should end with /input.

Comment: this is with the **print value** `<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="55342320-29fc-b246-abd3-499948d5fd3a", element="f7618fdc-05a3-de4d-aef6-6b1fc9463a47")>`

Comment: I obtained the xpath with the FirePath extension in FireFox

Comment: Try this xpath: url = ".//*[@id='answer']/section/table/tbody/tr[45]/td[4]" Then get its text attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The xpath which you have used for url is incorrect:

**Xpath Used:**

url = ".//*[@id='answer']/section/table/tbody/tr[45]/td[4]/text()[1]"

**It should be:**

url = ".//*[@id='answer']/section/table/tbody/tr[45]/td[4]"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of xpath you should use `ID` with `BeautifulSoup` like this:

```
for row in soup.find_all('td',attrs={"id" : "divider"}):
        print row.text
```

This wil solve your problem. :) Happy coding